# What does underscore wrap function do?

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

Looking at the example given here (http://underscorejs.org/#wrap), I don't really understand what wrap is doing ... Even more so, when the function is "wrapped" it feels the parameters have to be set (for example, what about doing hello('john')?  Are there other examples available that explains what wrap is all about? What would be a typical use case for it?
Thanks! 
C

Answer (score 1):

`_.wrap()` can accept more parameters in callback function other than the function you have. For example to make your `hello('John')` example work we need some modification on the example code to be

```
var hello = function(name) { return "hello: " + name; };
hello = _.wrap(hello, function(func,name) {
  return "before, " + func(name) + ", after";
});
hello('John');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is clearer now. What I understand is that the signature of the callback function in wrap is the one that corresponds to the function that is passed as the first argument in wrap.

Comment: No , The callback is different it can accept more arguments than the original function and the function `hello` is the first argument in the callback `func` check this https://jsfiddle.net/engmzizo/14ykdr3e/